# A "No results" View problem

Tags: 7, views

I would just like to hear a confirmation from someone:
If I have a View A that displays View B in case of No results, does the View B display with all its attachments? Somehow I cannot get this cascade to work. The attachment does not show and I'm not sure it's because of limitation or is it me (again)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it was me, I have not provided the specific view display, and the "default" did not work. No wonder. Sometimes asking a question in the air makes the answers come along magically.